# In Matthew 21:17, why does Jesus leave Jerusalem and go to Bethany?

Tags: matthew, jesus

In Matt. 21:17 and Matt. 26:30 we’re told that Jesus left the city at night. Why would Jesus leave Jerusalem and sleep elsewhere? Why didn’t He just sleep in Jerusalem ?

> [Mat 21:17 NLT] (17) Then he returned to Bethany, where he stayed overnight.
>
> [Mat 26:30 NLT] (30) Then they sang a hymn and went out to the Mount of Olives.

Comment: He was probably staying with his good friends Simon, Mary, Martha, and Lazarus in Bethany.

Answer (score 3):

The matter of the fig tree between Bethany and Jerusalem (and its being cursed and then withering) is relevant and the implications of how unfruitful Israel had become under the unspiritual administration of Pharisees and scribes and Herodians.

Instead of recognizing the failure of the first humanity and the need of redemption ; and instead of looking for, and welcoming the Messiah who would provide such redemption, the hierarchy (with the consent of the people) took over that which was God's and turned it into a facade of what Israel should truly have been.

It became unfruitful and, therefore, also inhospitable to the one who came to be its King. 'Come, this is the heir' they say, in parabolic prophecy. And so they reject his ministry and he chooses not to spend the night in the environs of Jerusalem and the temple, preferring the place of Bethany where such as Mary dwell who 'sat at his feet' and heard his word, together with Martha and Lazarus.